# Baffling windows command behavior (for /F...)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script that checks for local mods in a git repo.  I just need a yes/no output but I want to exclude untracked files.

Here's what I see at the command line when I include untracked files:

```
C:\local_workspace>git status --porcelain
 M EWARM/stm32u575xx_flash.icf
 M EWARM/stm32u575xx_sram.icf
?? EWARM/bui.h
?? EWARM/gen_build_info_header_git.bat
?? EWARM/test.h
?? EWARM/test2.h
```

I can work with that using the **for** command:

```
C:\local_workspace>for /F "delims=" %i in ('git status --porcelain') do (echo [%i])

C:\local_workspace>(echo [ M EWARM/stm32u575xx_flash.icf] )
[ M EWARM/stm32u575xx_flash.icf]

C:\local_workspace>(echo [ M EWARM/stm32u575xx_sram.icf] )
[ M EWARM/stm32u575xx_sram.icf]

C:\local_workspace>(echo [?? EWARM/bui.h] )
[?? EWARM/bui.h]

C:\local_workspace>(echo [?? EWARM/gen_build_info_header_git.bat] )
[?? EWARM/gen_build_info_header_git.bat]

C:\local_workspace>(echo [?? EWARM/test.h] )
[?? EWARM/test.h]

C:\local_workspace>(echo [?? EWARM/test2.h] )
[?? EWARM/test2.h]
```

Here's what I see if I exclude tracked files:

```
C:\local_workspace>git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
 M EWARM/stm32u575xx_flash.icf
 M EWARM/stm32u575xx_sram.icf
```

Now let's try **for**:

```
C:\local_workspace>for /F "delims=" %i in ('git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no') do (echo [%i])

C:\local_workspace>
```

There's no output!  Why not?

Comment: I believe you have to escape the `=` (to be `--untracked-files^=no`), but I don't have `git` installed so I can't confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` loops treat `=` as whitespace, so for all intents and purposes, your code is trying to process the command `git status --porcelain --untracked-files no`, which is invalid.

In order to preserve the `=`, it needs to be escaped with a `^`: `git status --porcelain --untracked-files^=no`